# How to remove ^M characters in the middle of each line in vi editor

Tags: unix, replace, vi

I am trying to remove the control characters from the middle of each line in a file. Here is my data below. I used the below command but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Command:
:%s/^M//g

Data:
53,v42,p11,51097,310780,ok^M,fraud
56,v45,p11,260,1925,ok^M,fraud
68,v42,p11,51282,278770,ok^M,fraud
96,v49,p14,212,1545,ok^M,fraud
163,v50,p20,373819,1006375,ok^M,fraud
204,v50,p26,36917,117195,ok^M,fraud
241,v70,p33,21777,91360,ok^M,fraud

Output Warning:
E486: Pattern not found: ^M
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this post: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/150/remove-m-characters-at-end-of-lines-in-vi/

```
To remove the ^M characters at the end of all lines in vi, use:

:%s/^V^M//g

The ^v is a CONTROL-V character and ^m is a CONTROL-M. When you type this, it will look like this:

:%s/^M//g
```

The basic reasoning is that typing ^M searches for the literal interpretation, two characters of ^ and M where instead you want to construct the actual control character from your input.

Comment: Doh! Just when I was about to press "Send" :-) But anyway, good answer!

Comment: I still don't get your answer.Also I already visited that link before and tried using the same command but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you typing ^M or holding control, hitting v, holding control hitting m? I've never had doing this in the past myself. What OS? Are you using a terminal program like PuTTY?

Comment: If I type "^M" from keyboard it says pattern ^M not found and if if I say "Ctrl +M" then it immediately goes away.

Comment: And if you say `Ctrl +V` followed by `Ctrl +M` what appears?

Answer (score 1):

yeah, you got hold 'Ctrl' and key 'v', then hold 'Ctrl' and key 'm', not literally key in '^v' and '^m'.

Answer (score -1):

How to remove ^M from unix files using VI editor
use this command.

:%s(Ctrl+V)(Ctrl+M)/

Important!! – press (Ctrl-v) (Ctrl-m) combination to enter ^M character, dont use “^” and M.

Comment: hmm .. question or answer?

Comment: Not: %s(Ctrl+V)(Ctrl+M)/.  You were missing the starting / and the trailing /g.  You mean: %s/(Ctrl+V)(Ctrl+M)//g.